# Why do newlines break ANSI cursors?

Tags: bash, unix, posix, ansi-escape, tput

In a contrived example, if I have the following:

```sh
sup="$(printf "\e[s" > /dev/tty; printf "one" > /dev/tty; printf "\e[u\e[Jtwo" > /dev/tty)"
```

The output will successfully erase `one` leaving only:

```
two
```

However, if I use `echo "one"` to print a newline with it:

```sh
sup="$(printf "\e[s" > /dev/tty; echo "one" > /dev/tty; printf "\e[u\e[Jtwo" > /dev/tty)"
```

Then the output is:

```
one
two
```

Why would the newline break the cursor handling? And how could I work around it?

A more comprehensive example would be:

```sh
sup="$(printf "\e[s" > /dev/tty; for (( i=0; i<5; i++)); do echo -e "a random number is:\n$RANDOM" > /dev/tty; sleep 1; printf "\e[u\e[J" > /dev/tty; done; echo 'result')"
echo "sup=$sup" # sup=result
```

Comment: Why are you assigning the output to a variable? Since everything is redirected to /dev/tty, the variable will get an empty string.

Comment: The examples are contrived to simplify a requirement of newlines, command substitution, and TTY erasure. The actual use case is assigning the stdout result of a command that asks the user a series of questions and erases the questions once completed. [1](https://github.com/bevry/dorothy/blob/e5eb65dae2129703e7f336df7f9ae34b4820218a/commands/ask), [2](https://github.com/bevry/dorothy/blob/e5eb65dae2129703e7f336df7f9ae34b4820218a/commands/choose-menu), the real commands currently use `clear` which erases everything.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you're writing to the last line of the window. Writing a newline will cause the window contents to scroll. When you restore the cursor position with `ESC [ u`, it returns to the physical position in the window that was saved with `ESC [ s`, not the position in the scroll buffer. But the word `one` will have scrolled up one line, so `two` will be written to the line after it rather than overwriting it.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to still have newlines visually, but have the cursor ignore/bypass/workaround them?

Comment: Use different cursor motion commands, such as cursor-up and move-to-beginning of line.

Comment: I would have to count the amount of lines then right?

Comment: Yes, you would need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Barmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69134577/130638) alluded to, the reason why restore cursor does not work, is that saving the cursor only saves the left/right margins, not the row:

> Saves the cursor position/state in SCO console mode.[22] In vertical split screen mode, instead used to set (as CSI n ; n s) or reset left and right margins.[23]
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CUP

I was able to come up with a portable solution that does not need me to count line numbers.

### `tty.bash`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# sourced from:
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/69138082/130638
# inspired by:
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88304/50703
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/2575525/130638
# https://askubuntu.com/a/366158/22776
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/5810220/130638
get_tty_snapshot () {
    local pos oldstty y x y_offset="${1:-0}" x_offset="${2:-0}"
    exec < /dev/tty
    oldstty=$(stty -g)
    stty raw -echo min 0
    echo -en "\e[6n" > /dev/tty
    IFS=';' read -r -d R -a pos
    stty "$oldstty"
    y="$((${pos[0]:2} - 2 + y_offset))"
    x="$((pos[1] - 1 + x_offset))"
    echo -en "\e[${y};${x}H\e[J"
}
use_tty_snapshot () {
    echo -en "$1" > /dev/tty
}
```

### `embed.bash`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source "./tty.bash"

tty_snapshot="$(get_tty_snapshot)"

for (( i=0; i<5; i++)); do
    echo -e "one random number $RANDOM\nanother random number: $RANDOM" > /dev/tty
    sleep 1
    use_tty_snapshot "$tty_snapshot"
done

echo 'result'
```

### `example.bash`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "ask result"
result="$(./test-cursor-embed)"
echo "got result=[$result]"
```