# Get terminal position from Ruby

Tags: ruby, terminal, terminfo

There has absolutely got to be a better way to do this.

```
temp_file ||= Tempfile.new()
system("stty -echo; tput u7; read -d R x; stty echo; echo ${x#??} > #{temp_file.path}")
temp_file.gets.chomp.split(';').map(&:to_i)
```

Basically, I'm running the bash script from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575037/how-to-get-the-cursor-position-in-bash) in a sub process and then reading the output from a redirected file.

Without using C or any gems (stdlib okay) what is a better way to do this?  Cross compatibility is not of great concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a pure ruby implementation of getting cursor position:

```
require 'io/console'

class Cursor
  class << self
    def pos
      res = ''
      $stdin.raw do |stdin|
        $stdout << "\e[6n"
        $stdout.flush
        while (c = stdin.getc) != 'R'
          res << c if c
        end
      end
      m = res.match /(?<row>\d+);(?<column>\d+)/
      { row: Integer(m[:row]), column: Integer(m[:column]) }
    end
  end
end

puts Cursor.pos  #=> {:row=>25, :column=>1}
```

`tput u7` was replaced with echoing `\e[6n` to `$stdout`. It is probably less portable but helps us to use only ruby code.

Answer (score 2):

[curses](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/curses/1.9.2/frames) is in the stdlib, but it's a mess.

Comment: It's for a multi-line "status bar" type thing, so I'm trying not to use the full on curses-lib.  I can get this done without it, it's just. so. ugly.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/eclubb/ncurses-ruby

You could try this in Ruby. It seems to have the curX and curY stuff that you need.