# How can I get position of cursor in terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, position, text-cursor

I know I may save position using `tput sc`, but how can I read it's position to the variable? I need the number of row. I don't want to use curses/ncurses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the cursor position in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575037/how-to-get-the-cursor-position-in-bash)

Comment: I can't expect that the user has bash. He may use csh or etc.

Answer (score 26):

At ANSI compatible terminals, printing the sequence `ESC[6n` will report the cursor position to the application as (as though typed at the keyboard) `ESC[n;mR`, where `n` is the row and `m` is the column.

Example:

```
~$ echo -e "\033[6n"
```

EDITED:

You should make sure you are reading the keyboard input. The terminal will "type" just the `ESC[n;mR` sequence (no ENTER key). In `bash` you can use something like:

```
echo -ne "\033[6n"            # ask the terminal for the position
read -s -d\[ garbage          # discard the first part of the response
read -s -d R foo              # store the position in bash variable 'foo'
echo -n "Current position: "
echo "$foo"                   # print the position
```

Explanation: the `-d R` (delimiter) argument will make `read` stop at the char `R` instead of the default record delimiter (`ENTER`). This will store `ESC[n;m` in `$foo`. The cut is using `[` as delimiter and picking the second field, letting `n;m` (row;column).

I don't know about other shells. Your best shot is some oneliner in Perl, Python or something. In Perl you can start with the following (untested) snippet:

```
~$ perl -e '$/ = "R";' -e 'print "\033[6n";my $x=<STDIN>;my($n, $m)=$x=~m/(\d+)\;(\d+)/;print "Current position: $m, $n\n";'
```

For example, if you enter:

```
~$ echo -e "z033[6n"; cat > foo.txt
```

Press [ENTER] a couple times and then [CRTL]+[D]. Then try:

```
~$ cat -v foo.txt
^[[47;1R
```

The `n` and `m` values are 47 and 1. Check the [wikipedia article on ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for more information.

Before the Internet, in the golden days of the [BBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulletin_board_system), old farts like me had a lot of fun with these codes.

Comment: Hmm... it always returns me `;1R`.

Comment: @ciembor, that's because the text is echoed to the terminal, which in turn might interpret the escape sequence and cut off things.

Comment: I've just edited the bash example a little. For example using `-s` with `read` so that it doesn't echo the response to the screen. The first two lines now "silently" store the position in `foo`.

Comment: In the example after perl oneline. It is supposed to be "\033[6n" instead of "z033[6n" right ?

Comment: @deepakchethan good catch! In the Brazilian keyboard layout `\ ` and `z` are side by side.

Comment: How can you know which positions are allowed, i.e. how many "rows" / "columns" are there on the screen?