# How can I get the cursor's position in an ANSI terminal?

Tags: python, terminal

I want to get the cursor's position in a terminal window. I know I can `echo -e "\033[6n"` and `read` the output `-s` silently as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8353312/4532996), but how can I do this in Python?

I've tried [this contextmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16571630/4532996) like this:

```
with Capturing() as output:
    sys.stdout.write("\e[6n")
print(output)
```

but it only captures the `\e[6n` (`'\x1b[6n'`) escape sequence I write, not the `^[[x;yR1` sequence I need.

I've also tried spawning a `subprocess` and getting its output, but again, only the escape sequence I write is captured:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["echo", "\033[6n"], shell=False)
print(output)
```

`shell=True` makes the output be a list of empty strings.

Avoiding `curses` (because this is supposed to be a *simple*, poor man's cursor pos getter), how can I get the escape sequence returned by printing `\e[6n`?

Comment: Maybe you should be using curses instead. https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html

Comment: @jsbueno did you read the question? No curses, please.

Comment: That is why I did not try to answer with curses.  :-)  I am still thinking about your question - not sure if feasible without low level access to the system charcter devices themselves. For which Operating Systems you want this?

Comment: @jsbueno POSIX, (Unix + Linux) mostly, because I can have an ANSI term in Windows if i  use `colorama`, which is less huge than curses

Comment: Where are you viewing your output from stdout? using `\e[6n` should return the proper value `^[[76;5R` if run in terminal.

Comment: I think the way to go is to use ANSI to clear the screen, and account for the cursor position on your program side. That would not prevent your users from typing in and changing the cursor position, though.

Comment: BTW, there is a reason curses is big - it it is taht this kindo f thing is not trivial to do. Maybe you should also think about moving your application to a graphic UI or to to a web interface, if this is getting your work stuck.

Comment: @jsbueno Actually, this *is* the work. see https://github.com/catb0t/whereami and https://github.com/catb0t/input_constrain

Comment: @l'L'l I'm just printing it in the terminal. What's your Python version and terminal emulator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply read `sys.stdin` yourself to get the value.
I found the answer in a question just like yours, but for one trying to do that from a C program:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/get-cursor-position-in-c-947833/

So, when I tried something along that from the Python interactive terminal:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.write("\x1b[6n");a=sys.stdin.read(10)
]^[[46;1R
>>>
>>> a
'\x1b[46;1R'
>>> sys.stdin.isatty()
True
```

You will have to use other ANSI tricks/position/reprint to avoid the output actually showing up on the terminal, and prevent blocking on stdin read - but I think it can be done with some trial and error.

Comment: That works perfectly; I don't know why I didn't try reading `stdin`.

Comment: Is it possible to get the maximal allowed position, ie the terminal's "resolution"?

Comment: Yes, but not through an ANSI sequence (or maybe, even as well through an ANSI sequence, these things are complex) - but Python has a call in the `os` module: `os.terminal_size` will return a named-tuple with the number of columns and lines.

Comment: It nicely prints to the terminal, but does not read anything. Proper solution is WereCatf's!

Comment: @Jay If you're just looking for the total column/line count of the current terminal, then if you're using Bash you can get these values from the `$COLUMNS` and `$LINES` env variables which will be defined if the curernt shell is an interactive (you can also get them in a non-interactive shell if you explicitly set bash's `checkwinsize` option). You can also detect changes to the terminal size by trapping the `SIGWINCH` signal which will allow you to specify a function to be executed whenever the terminal size changes, inside of which you can then read new values from `$COLUMNS` and `$LINES`.

Answer (score 19):

While the question here on Stack Overflow is old, it's certainly not outdated, and as such I wrote a complete example of how to do this.

The basic approach is:

1. Enable processing of ANSI escape sequences on *stdout*.
2. Disable ECHO and line mode on *stdin*.
3. Send the ANSI sequence to query cursor position on *stdout*.
4. Read the reply on *stdin*.
5. Restore the settings for *stdin* and *stdout*.

For step 1, under Linux handling of ANSI escape sequences on *stdout* should be enabled by default, but under Windows they aren't, at least at the moment, which is why the example below uses SetConsoleMode to enable those. With regards to the *kernel32.GetStdHandle()* - calls, the Windows standard handle for *stdin* is -10 and for *stdout* it's -11, and we are just getting the file descriptors for those. These are Windows-only functions.

As for Linux, we can use termios to disable/enable ECHO and line mode. Of note is that termios isn't available under Windows.

For step 2, any input on *stdin* is buffered and only sent forward line-by-line, but we want to read all input on *stdin* as soon as possible. We also want to disable ECHO, so the reply to step 3 doesn't get printed out to the console.

Just for a good measure, the example below will give a result of (-1, -1) if something went wrong, so your code could e.g. try again.

```
import sys, re
if(sys.platform == "win32"):
    import ctypes
    from ctypes import wintypes
else:
    import termios

def cursorPos():
    if(sys.platform == "win32"):
        OldStdinMode = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD()
        OldStdoutMode = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD()
        kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
        kernel32.GetConsoleMode(kernel32.GetStdHandle(-10), ctypes.byref(OldStdinMode))
        kernel32.SetConsoleMode(kernel32.GetStdHandle(-10), 0)
        kernel32.GetConsoleMode(kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11), ctypes.byref(OldStdoutMode))
        kernel32.SetConsoleMode(kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11), 7)
    else:
        OldStdinMode = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)
        _ = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)
        _[3] = _[3] & ~(termios.ECHO | termios.ICANON)
        termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSAFLUSH, _)
    try:
        _ = ""
        sys.stdout.write("\x1b[6n")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        while not (_ := _ + sys.stdin.read(1)).endswith('R'):
            True
        res = re.match(r".*\[(?P<y>\d*);(?P<x>\d*)R", _)
    finally:
        if(sys.platform == "win32"):
            kernel32.SetConsoleMode(kernel32.GetStdHandle(-10), OldStdinMode)
            kernel32.SetConsoleMode(kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11), OldStdoutMode)
        else:
            termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSAFLUSH, OldStdinMode)
    if(res):
        return (res.group("x"), res.group("y"))
    return (-1, -1)

x, y = cursorPos()
print(f"Cursor x: {x}, y: {y}")
```

The resulting output should be akin to this:

```
Cursor x: 1, y: 30
```

Additional links that may be of use, if one wishes to dig deeper into all this and e.g. expand on the functionality here: [Man-page for Linux's termios](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/manpages-dev/termios.3.en.html), [Windows SetConsoleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode), [Windows GetConsoleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolemode), [Wikipedia-entry for ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Comment: Why that `while not (_ := _ + sys.stdin.read(1)).endswith('R'): True`? Wouldn't it  be easier and simpler to read `while not.... :pass`?

Comment: If you're referring to my use of "True" there, we're talking about a single word: I don't see how it'd be any easier or simpler to read. It'd be more pythonic to use "pass", yes, I'll grant you that. There is no real reason why I used "True"; I just simply wasn't thinking and I'm so used to doing loops in shell-scripts that it slipped in there.