# Python: Determine if terminal's cursor is in the start of the line

Tags: python, printing, terminal, console, cursor-position

I notice an annoying occurrence when printing logs to the console during a `tqdm`-wrapped loop. In that case, the logs begin in the same line as the `tqdm` printouts right after them.

I figure that I can prepend `"\r"` to all logs, but I'd rather just find out if the cursor is currently at the start of the line or not. Does python expose that information?

Thanks.

Comment: There is related (actually, reverse) problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707229/tqdm-printing-to-newline Also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526014/how-can-i-get-the-cursors-position-in-an-ansi-terminal use interaction with terminal (sys.stdin reading) to get the cursor position I'd post this links as comment, but I have no rating to do this

Comment: @dkotenko Thank you, but that I know and doesn't help me.