# How to update data on multiple lines of console

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

I want to display data on two lines of the console. I just want to update the two lines everytime.

What I have done till now is -

```
var _logInline = function(alpha, bravo) {
    process.stdout.cursorTo(0, 0);
    process.stdout.clearLine();
    process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
    process.stdout.write(alpha.toString());
    process.stdout.write('\n');
    process.stdout.clearLine();
    process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
    process.stdout.write(bravo.toString());
    process.stdout.write('\n');

};

var delay = 1000;
var time = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    time++;
    _logInline('alpha-' + time, 'bravo-' + time * time);
}, delay);
```

The obvious problem with this solution is that the cursor goes to the top of the window. I don't want that, instead it should display the content where ever the cursor is at the moment. Probably I need to get the current cursor position first in my logic. Is there a way to do that?

Alternative and the most preferred solution would be to get a lib which can do the same thing

EDIT:
I have seen some questions on stackoverflow which give an option of logging without new line but this is not exactly what I want. I want multiple no-new-line logging.

Comment: You can get the cursor position ([see this gist](https://gist.github.com/viatropos/3765464)) with bash but does not work in windows. The easiest solution I have found: http://pastebin.com/y69by2QE (but use `cursorTo(0, 0)`).

Answer (score 1):

ncurses is the most powerful library I've used to control the terminal, there is an excellent npm package by mscdex that binds to the c library https://npmjs.org/package/ncurses

But it may be a little overkill for your needs, here is an alternative solution but it involves using a bash script:

Based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/3765464) I've put together the following code adapted to your example,
you can [download it from gist](https://gist.github.com/alfonsodev/7792365) or read it here, don't forget to give exec permissions to the bash script with:

```
  chmod +x cursor-position.sh
```

**cursor-position.js**

```
module.exports = function(callback) {
  require('child_process').exec('./cursor-position.sh', function(error, stdout, stderr){
    callback(error, JSON.parse(stdout));
  });
}
```

**cursor-position.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
# based on a script from http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575037/how-to-get-the-cursor-position-in-bash
exec < /dev/tty
oldstty=$(stty -g)
stty raw -echo min 0
# on my system, the following line can be replaced by the line below it
echo -en "\033[6n" > /dev/tty
# tput u7 > /dev/tty    # when TERM=xterm (and relatives)
IFS=';' read -r -d R -a pos
stty $oldstty
# change from one-based to zero based so they work with: tput cup $row $col
row=$((${pos[0]:2} - 1))    # strip off the esc-[
col=$((${pos[1]} - 1))
echo \{\"row\":$row,\"column\":$col\}
```

**index.js**

```
var getCursorPosition = require('./cursor-position');

var _logInline = function(row, msg) {
  if(row >= 0) row --; //litle correction
  process.stdout.cursorTo(0, row);
  process.stdout.clearLine();
  process.stdout.cursorTo(0, row);
  process.stdout.write(msg.toString());
};

var delay = 1000;
var time = 0;

//Start by getting the current position
getCursorPosition(function(error, init) {
  setInterval(function() {
      time++;
      _logInline(init.row, 'alpha-' + time);
      _logInline(init.row + 1, 'bravo-' + time * time);
  }, delay);
});
```

Comment: broken link to gist example

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about doing this for a long while...

Here is a very very naive solution for multiline:

```js
import {execSync} from "child_process";

var util = require('util');
var x = 0;
var y = 100;
setInterval(function () {
    execSync('tput cuu1 tput el tput cuu1 tput el', {stdio: 'inherit'});
    process.stdout.write(`hello1: ${x++}\nhello2: ${y++}\r`);  // needs return '/r'
    // util.print('hello: ' + x + '\r');  // could use this too
}, 1000);
```

I will update when I will have a more robust implementation.