# How do you dynamically change/overwrite a console log with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

I'm working with JavaScript/Node and have a Websocket with a server that is sending a constantly updating string. My goal is to log the string dynamically in the console, so if the sequence of strings from the stream is
`[string1, string1, string2, string2, string2, string3]`, then rather than have the console show

```
string1
string1
string2
string2
string2
string3
```

I want the console to show

```
stringI
```

Where `stringI` is constantly updating and `I` is in {1,2,3}

Currently, I'm doing this with

```
process.stdout.clearLine(0)
process.stdout.cursorTo(0)
process.stdout.write(new_string)
```

But I run into issues when the string is greater than one line length in the console.

**Does anyone know how I can dynamically overwrite a constantly updating string in the console? Thanks!**

Comment: just end the written string with a return `\r`, as for multiline updates you could slice the string to fit `new_string.slice(0, process.stdout.columns)` or see [How to update data on multiple lines of console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424723/how-to-update-data-on-multiple-lines-of-console)

Comment: You can start by reading here: https://dustinpfister.github.io/2019/09/19/nodejs-ansi-escape-codes/

Answer (score 0):

truncation could be an easy option:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
exec("truncate -s 0 console.log");
```