# Configure shell to always print prompt on new line, like zsh

Tags: bash, shell, prompt

If a command's output does not end with a `\n`, the next prompt appears, awkwardly, immediately afterwards:

```
$ echo -n hai
hai$
```

I just noticed a colleague whose shell (zsh, for what it's worth) is configured to print a `%` (with background and foreground colours inverted for emphasis) followed by a `\n` in such cases:

```
$ echo -n hai
hai%
$
```

I'd like to do the same. I use Bash. Is this possible? If so, what would I add to my ~/.bashrc?

---

**UPDATE**

I've spent several hours gaining an understanding of how gniourf_gniourf's solution works. I'll share my findings here, in case they are of use to others.

- `ESC[6n` is the control sequence introducer for accessing the cursor position (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).
- `\e` is not a valid representation of ESC when using `echo` on OS X (https://superuser.com/q/33914/176942). `\033` can be used instead.
- IFS is Bash's internal field separator (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#IFSREF).
- `read -sdR` looks like shorthand for `read -s -d -R`, but in fact the "R" is not a flag, it's the *value* of the `-d` (delimiter) option. I decided to write `read -s -d R` instead to avoid confusion.
- The double-parentheses construct, `(( ... ))`, permits arithmetic expansion and evaluation (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html).

Here's the relevant snippet from my [.bashrc](https://github.com/davidchambers/dotfiles/blob/ed0ad76b5a620edc51632e077289dbd8b3ab2754/.bashrc):

```
set_prompt() {
  # CSI 6n reports the cursor position as ESC[n;mR, where n is the row
  # and m is the column. Issue this control sequence and silently read
  # the resulting report until reaching the "R". By setting IFS to ";"
  # in conjunction with read's -a flag, fields are placed in an array.
  local curpos
  echo -en '\033[6n'
  IFS=';' read -s -d R -a curpos
  curpos[0]="${curpos[0]:2}"  # strip leading ESC[
  (( curpos[1] > 1 )) && echo -e '\033[7m%\033[0m'

  # set PS1...
}

export PROMPT_COMMAND=set_prompt
```

Note: The `curpos[0]="${curpos[0]:2}"` line is unnecessary. I included it so this code could be used in a context where the row is also relevant.

Comment: Why not ask him how it is done. It will most likely be the same snippet in your `~/.bashrc` as his `~/.zshrc` .This question may be better suited for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), but where you wanting to only append to lines without \n breaks?

Comment: I did ask him, and we had a look in his ~/.zshrc but couldn't find the code responsible. Yes, I'd like to append only to output that does not end with `\n`.

Comment: This is something I could not find last night on Google and seems to be zch specific as it does have alot of new line handling information out there. Im gonna look into this later tonight as I want to know how to do this myself now.

Comment: "what would I add to my ~/.bashrc?" `exec zsh`.

Comment: zsh uses the [`$COLUMN - 1` spaces then `\r` trick](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/19390a1ba8dc983b0a1379058e90cd51ce156815/Src/utils.c#L1599) internally, if anyone's still curious why they can't find it in their friends' .zshrc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A little trick using [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Printing-a-Prompt):

> The value of the variable `PROMPT_COMMAND` is examined just before Bash prints each primary prompt. If `PROMPT_COMMAND` is set and has a non-null value, then the value is executed just as if it had been typed on the command line.

Hence, if you put this in your `.bashrc`:

```
_my_prompt_command() {
    local curpos
    echo -en "\E[6n"
    IFS=";" read -sdR -a curpos
    ((curpos[1]!=1)) && echo -e '\E[1m\E[41m\E[33m%\E[0m'
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=_my_prompt_command
```

you'll be quite good. Feel free to use other fancy colors in the `echo "%"` part. You can even put the content of that in a variable so that you can modify it on the fly.

The trick: obtain the column of the cursor (with `echo -en "\E[6n"` followed by the `read` command) before printing the prompt and if it's not 1, print a `%` and a newline.

Pros:

- pure bash (no external commands),
- no subshells,
- leaves your `PS1` all nice and clean: if you want to change your `PS1` sometimes (I do this when I work in deeply nested directory — I don't like having prompts that run on several miles), this will still work.

---

As tripleee comments, you could use *`stty` instead of echoing a hard-coded control sequence.* But that uses an external command and is not pure bash anymore. Adapt to your needs.

---

Regarding your problem with the ugly character codes that get randomly printed: this might be because there's still some stuff in the tty buffer. There might be several fixes:

1. Turn off and then on the `echo` of the terminal, using `stty`.

   ```
   set_prompt() {
       local curpos
       stty -echo
       echo -en '\033[6n'
       IFS=';' read -d R -a curpos
       stty echo
       (( curpos[1] > 1 )) && echo -e '\033[7m%\033[0m'
   }
   PROMPT_COMMAND=set_prompt
   ```

   the main difference is that the `echo`/`read` combo has been wrapped with `stty -echo`/`stty echo` that respectively disables and enables echoing on terminal (that's why the `-s` option to `read` is now useless). In this case you won't get the cursor position correctly and this might lead to strange error messages, or the `%` not being output at all.
2. Explicitly clear the tty buffer:

   ```
   set_prompt() {
       local curpos
       while read -t 0; do :; done
       echo -en '\033[6n'
       IFS=';' read -s -d R -a curpos
       (( curpos[1] > 1 )) && echo -e '\033[7m%\033[0m'
   }
   PROMPT_COMMAND=set_prompt
   ```
3. Just give up if the tty buffer can't be cleaned:

   ```
   set_prompt() {
       local curpos
       if ! read -t 0; then
           echo -en '\033[6n'
           IFS=';' read -s -d R -a curpos
           (( curpos[1] > 1 )) && echo -e '\033[7m%\033[0m'
       # else
       #     here there was still stuff in the tty buffer, so I couldn't query the cursor position
       fi
   }
   PROMPT_COMMAND=set_prompt
   ```

As a side note: instead of `read`ing in an array `curpos`, you can directly obtain the position of the cursor in variables, say, `curx` and `cury` as so:

```
IFS='[;' read -d R _ curx cury
```

If you only need the y-position `cury`:

```
IFS='[;' read -d R _ _ cury
```

Comment: Impressive! That's a beautiful solution. Last question: why quote the function name, why not simply `PROMPT_COMMAND=_my_prompt_command`

Comment: @janos thanks for your comment. You're right, the quotes are useless there, I'll remove them.

Comment: I suppose you could gain some portability by using `stty` instead of `echo`ing a hard-coded control sequence.

Comment: @tripleee you're right. I only wanted this to be 100% pure bash and not use external commands.

Comment: You don't need the `stty` inline. Something like `q=$(stty whatever); fun () { echo -n "$q"; }`

Comment: Very nice answer. I spent some time learning how it works and updated the question with my findings.

Comment: @davidchambers was all this so difficult to decipher? `:)` I only hope you learned some interesting stuff in the process! I wish you good luck, and I hope this snippet of code will follow you for a long time!

Comment: Having used this for a few hours, I've noticed that `read` is occasionally *not* silent (something like `^[[20;1R` is printed). Any ideas as to the cause of this unpredictable behaviour?

Comment: The `stty -echo` trick can be shortened to just `IFS='[;' read -s -r -d'R' -p$'\033[6n' _ _ cur_y` instead of `stty;echo;read;stty`. To see why the trick is actually always necessary, try not using stty and place a sleep between the echo and the read: there will always be garbage echoed to the terminal.

Comment: I should also point out that `while read -t 0; do :; done` does _not_ clear the buffer, but is an infinite loop whenever there's any input ready to be read. The man page says: "If TIMEOUT is 0, 'read' returns immediately, without trying to read any data."

Comment: Another interesting observation: `read -t 0` doesn't detect pending input if the input doesn't contain a newline due to [terminal in canonical mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Canonical-or-Not.html), so it's either an endless loop or noop. To be able to see input without newline, `stty -icanon; stty icanon` is necessary before the `read -t 0`. So I now have: https://github.com/liskin/dotfiles/blob/322ad36ec1d3ee5485c7b637e4c41fff7ea6745c/.bashrc.d/20_prompt.sh#L12-L19

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Gilles on [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60459/how-to-make-bash-put-prompt-on-a-new-line-after-cat-command):

> You can make the bash display its prompt on the next line if the previous command left the cursor somewhere other than the last margin. Put this in your .bashrc (variation by [GetFree](https://serverfault.com/questions/97503/bash-how-to-know-if-the-last-commands-output-ends-with-a-newline-or-not) of a proposal by [Dennis Williamson](https://serverfault.com/questions/97503/bash-how-to-know-if-the-last-commands-output-ends-with-a-newline-or-not/97543#97543))

From the two linked answers I distilled this solution:

```
PS1='\[\e[7m%\e[m\]$(printf "%$((COLUMNS-1))s")\r$ '
```

Explanation:

- `\[\e[7m%\e[m\]` -- reverse video percent sign
- `printf "%$((COLUMNS-1))s"` -- `COLUMNS-1` spaces. The `COLUMNS` variable stores the width of your terminal if the `checkwinsize` options is set. Since the `printf` is within a `$()` sub-shell, instead of printing to the screen its output will be added to `PS1`
- `\r` a carriage return character

So, basically, it's a `%` sign, a long sequence of spaces, followed by a return key. This works, but to be honest I don't understand why this has the desired effect. Specifically, why does it look like it adds a line break only when it's needed, otherwise no extra line break? Why are the spaces necessary there?

Comment: "This does not fully address your question, as I don't know how to put a `%` at the end of the line like `zsh` does." -- Dennis Williamson's answer (to which you linked) does this.

Comment: it works by not outputting a line break at all - it spaces to the right edge of the screen then outputs a carriage return - not newline - to move the cursor to the beginning of the current line.  If the previous line ended anywhere but at the beginning of the line, then the spaces will wrap, and the CR will just go to the beginning of that short line.

Comment: @evilotto what about the number of spaces? Why is it significant to have precisely `COLUMNS-1` spaces?

Answer (score 0):

if you do `echo $PS1` you will see de current code of your prompt like this:
`\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$`

now prepend it with a `\n` like this:

`PS1="\n\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$"`

now your prompt will always begin on a new line.

Comment: That would add an extra `\n` in the common case (when a command's output ends with `\n`).

Comment: @davidchambers Yes :-)

Comment: Yeah I was thinking PS1 first, but the OP wants to append only when the previous output did not have a /n return.

Comment: You don't address the question at all. The OP asked for a newline *only* when the output doesn't have one, and he also asked for an indication with an inverted `%`. Btw I just installed `zsh` and it does this by default, so it might very well be magic...

Comment: @janos: Don't be so harsh, I got him halfway with showing how to add something like a \n to the prompt. If you know better, show me the code.

Comment: @thom I didn't mean to be harsh, at all. But I still don't think you got him even halfway. My gut feeling is there won't be a good answer here. It's probably `zsh` magic that `bash` simply cannot do.

Comment: @janos: That is correct, this feature is not available in bash. The only way is to take the C-source from bash, patch it and recompile it. Changing the prompt is as far as it goes. Maybe the question could use an extra tag (ANSI C)