# Reading cursor position in a Java console application

Tags: java, console-application, bufferedreader, ansi-escape

I want to determine cursor position in a Java console application.

This can be achieved by the following ANSI code sequence:

```
ESC[6n
```

If I send that ANSI escape command I get the answer, but I can not retrieve it in Java.
This is what I have tried:

```
public class ConsoleTest {

    public static final String ANSI_GET_CURSOR_POSITION = "\u001B[6n";


    public ConsoleTest() {

        System.out.println(ANSI_GET_CURSOR_POSITION);

        BufferedReader obj = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));   
        String str = null;

        do {   

            try {
                str = obj.readLine();   
                System.out.println(str);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ConsoleTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } while(!str.equals("stop"));           


    }

}
```

This is what I get, even pressing ENTER does nothing:

```
% java -jar ConsoleTest.jar

^[[24;1R

stop               
stop
```

So apparently, console answers with the code but I can not read it in the Java application.

Comment: Does this help? [Java gotoxy(x,y) for console applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001335/java-gotoxyx-y-for-console-applications)

Comment: Your observation is wrong; pressing ENTER _does_ cause Java to read the response, but your code then _outputs_ that same response (`System.out.println(str)`) which does nothing. However, the response is not a line, so if you don't want to wait for ENTER, don't use `readLine`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question where you can find how to read the cursor position with simple Java program: [How to read the cursor position given by the terminal (ANSI Device Status Report) in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60134860/how-to-read-the-cursor-position-given-by-the-terminal-ansi-device-status-report/72991794#72991794)