# Bash echo end up on input line

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, gnome-terminal, ansi-escape

I'm using the escape sequence `\u001B[6n` to find the current terminal cursor location in linux. However, when I run the command `echo -e '\u001B[6n'`, the response is seemingly written as input to the terminal?

I'm trying to use this command from another process and so I need the result written to stdout directly. The below example of `echo -e '\u001B[6n' ; read -d R` therefore might seem fine in the console but does not work in practice.

1. Why is the response (at least seemingly) written to the input line of the terminal? Does echo yield this behaviour and if so why?
2. Is there a way to have the result from the echo printed "as usual" (to stdout), or is there another way (command) to retrieve the cursor location?

[image: echo -e '\u001B[6n']

**EDIT**

As this question got flagged as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575037/how-to-get-the-cursor-position-in-bash) question, I would like to highlight

1. the explicit requirement of *avoiding* the command `read`
2. The question as to why the output of `echo -e` (as well as `printf`) end up on the input line in the terminal

Comment: FYI, `echo -e` is not particularly good form -- bash has to literally violate the letter of the POSIX specification to provide it (unlike most bashisms which are in undefined space), and *doesn't* perform that violation in all modes and configurations (see the `xpg_echo` option's behavior, particularly in `set -o posix` mode). Consider using `printf '%b'` instead, as suggested in the APPLICATION USAGE section of [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html).

Comment: BTW, which terminal, specifically, supports this escape sequence, and in which emulation mode (that is, with which value for the `TERM` variable)? (Might be useful to anyone trying to reproduce the intended behavior).

Comment: I'm currently running this on the standard gnome-terminal  in Ubuntu 16.04 64bit.

Comment: $TERM returns xterm-256color

Comment: Actually it's not a duplicate (of the suggested q/a), since neither it nor any of the comments address OP's confusion regarding `read` and the standard input.