# Bash: Capitalize first letter of name and surname in .csv file

Tags: linux, bash, csv, while-loop

There is a acc.csv file, that contains name and surname in 3rd column (*ex: john smith*). I try capitalize firt letters (*John Smith*) and create a new file acc_new.csv with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3 

do
    for n in $col3; do
        n=${n^}
    done  

done < acc.csv > acc_new.csv
```

But acc_new.csv is empty. What is wrong with code?

acc.csv:

```
id,location,name
1,1,john smith
2,2,paul Robinson
3,3,Fidel guererro
...
```

expected output:

```
id,location,name
1,1,John Smith
2,2,Paul Robinson
3,3,Fidel Guererro
...
```

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the expected output.

Comment: The body of your loop doesn't output anything. There are no `echo` nor `printf` nor any commands inside.

Comment: Then in this case, how to save the changes?

Comment: Output the new line with `echo` or `printf`

Comment: In bash, variables are passed by value (except those with nameref attribute), not reference; changes you make on `n` are not saved to `col3`. Besides, I don't think bash is the perfect tool for performing this kind of transformation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original bash code read in and modified the contents of `acc.csv`, but did not organize or export the modified contents.

The modified code may help:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3 

do
    unset col3_new

    if [ "$col1" == id ]; then
        echo "${col1},${col2},${col3}"
        continue
    fi

    for n in $col3; do
        if [ -z "$col3_new" ]
        then
            col3_new=${n^}
        else
            col3_new+=" ${n^}"
        fi
    done  
    echo "${col1},${col2},${col3_new}"

done < acc.csv > acc_new.csv
```

Comment: I recive this:
Id,location,Name
1,1,Name
 John Smith
2,2,Name
 John Smith
 Paul Robinson
3,3,Name
 John Smith
 Paul Robinson
 Fidel Guererro

Comment: I added the missing `unset col3_new`. It should work now.

Comment: I added additional `if` statements to avoid capitalizing the title line

Comment: It looks much better!

Comment: If I have 2 or 3 values in 2nd column separeted with comma, how can I avoid this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in pure bash as you're attempting, but it's likely more efficient in another language.

Perl example:

```
$ perl -F, -lane '$F[2] =~ s/\b([[:alpha:]])/\u$1/g if $. > 1;
                  print join(",", @F)' acc.csv > acc_new.csv
$ cat acc_new.csv
id,location,name
1,1,John Smith
2,2,Paul Robinson
3,3,Fidel Guererro
```

This titlecases every letter in the third column (Skipping the first header line) at a word break - like the start of the field or after a space.

Comment: It's work! Thx! Could you explain used conditions for perl?

Comment: "used conditions"?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind using a line of perl ...

sample :

```
name,job,fee
aaaa,bbb,ccc
```

code

```
perl -lne 's/^./uc($&)/e  && print' < my.csv
```

or

```
perl -lne 's/^./\u$&/g  && print' < my.csv
```

output:

```
Name,job,fee
Aaaa,bbb,ccc
```

---

For your case that starts with numbers try this

```
perl -lpe 's/(?<=,)[a-z]/\u$&/ ' < smple.csv
```

output

```
id,Location,name
1,1,John smith
2,2,Paul Robinson
3,3,Fidel guererro
```

and if you want that only lines started with numbers be affected , first match numbers

```
perl -lpe '/^\d/ && s/(?<=,)[a-z]/\u$&/ ' < smple.csv
```

[ref](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ucfirst.html)

Comment: @oguz-ismail I linked that lines be in orange color, the same theme as stack-over-flow has ...

Comment: I got it, let's focus on the quality of the content rather than the aesthetic value

Comment: @oguzismail it is your opinion and not mine. Quality of an answer is scored by Up-vote / Down-vote not what I, you/, others think it is. Here is another answer of mine please read the first comments by **KamilCuk**  [Bash - Clearing the last output correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62038398/bash-clearing-the-last-output-correctly)

Comment: I didn't say your question is of low quality. What I meant was there is no point in decorating your post with colorful images, etc. since it doesn't add any extra value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `bash` and `awk`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cat acc.csv | awk '
    BEGIN {OFS=FS=","};
    NR>1{
        $3 = tolower($3);
        split($3, arr, " ");
        for(i in arr)
            sub(arr[i], toupper(substr(arr[i], 1, 1))substr(arr[i], 2), $3)
    }1' > acc_new.csv
```

Comment: How can I save changes in new file?

Comment: Thx for solution!