# How to get caret position without external libraries in C/C++ on linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, terminal, caret

I am trying to get the caret's (console cursor) position in ubuntu. I found a solution (here: https://thoughtsordiscoveries.wordpress.com/2017/04/26/set-and-read-cursor-position-in-terminal-windows-and-linux/ ) that makes use of ANSI codes, which looks like this:

```
printf("\033[6n");
scanf("\033[%d;%dR", &x, &y); // in x and y I save the position
```

The problem with this is that `printf("\033[6n");` prints stuff in the terminal, which is not something that I want. I tried to hide the output of `printf("\033[6n");` using the ANSI code `\033[8m`, but this only makes the characters invisible, which is not what I want. I want to get rid of the output completely. I know that you can redirect the output to `/dev/null` if I'm not mistaking, but I don't know if that won't mess up the cursor position then, I didn't try this yet.

So, one of the two options:

**1.** How can I hide the output of `printf` without messing up anything?

**OR**

**2.** Is there any other way to get the cursor position without external libraries? I believe it is possible with `<termios.h>`, but I couldn't find an explanation on how that works.

Comment: `prints stuff in the terminal` What does it print exactly? `without external libraries in C/C++ on linux?` Why without external libraries? Why not use ncurses? Basically you want to do the same as [this bash code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2575525/9072753) but in C.

Comment: @KamilCuk By "prints stuff in the terminal" I mean that `printf(\033[6n");"` prints `^[[45;1R` for example, if the cursor is at `x = 45` and `y = 1`. And no external libraries because I'm trying to do this by myself, it's not for something important, just personal knowledge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my terminal disabling ECHO and disable canonical mode, but setting terminal to RAW is probably just better. Following code misses a lot of error handling:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>    
int main() {
    int x, y;
    int t = STDOUT_FILENO;
    struct termios sav;
    tcgetattr(t, &sav);
    struct termios opt = sav;
    opt.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON);
    // but better just cfmakeraw(&opt);
    tcsetattr(t, TCSANOW, &opt);
    printf("\033[6n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("\033[%d;%dR", &x, &y);
    tcsetattr(t, TCSANOW, &sav);
    printf("Cursor pos is %d %d\n", x, y);
}
```